# CKAsset To NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, icloud, cloudkit

I've got a few plist files stored in an asset inside a CloudKit Record Type. I'm Having Trouble Understanding how to download the pilst from iCloud to the document directory folder.

```
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer defaultContainer] publicCloudDatabase];
CKRecordID *record = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"Charts"];
[publicDatabase fetchRecordWithID:record completionHandler:^(CKRecord *musicRecord, NSError *error) {
    // handle the error
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Plist Loaded %@", musicRecord.allKeys);
        NSData *Assetdata = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:musicRecord.allKeys.lastObject];            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *savePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"charts"];

        [Assetdata writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
    }
```

Any Help Is Much Appreciated

Comment: So what's not working?  Have you stepped thru within the debugger?

Comment: The Code above works fine. However the file that gets saved doesn't contain any data. So the issue I have is that I can't seem to get my plist on iCloud into my app.

Comment: The code doesn't work fine then.  Step thru and see if you can figure out what is failing.

Comment: My Mistake, I was simply using the wrong method. I should have been using CKFetchRecordsOperation instead of CKAsset. Thank You For Your Support